# How to get sum of specific criteria in MS Excel from one sheet to another (Single Spreadsheet)?

Tags: excel

[image: Sheet 1]

[image: Sheet 2]

```
=SUMIF(Sheet2!B:E, Sheet2!B2, Sheet2!B:E)
```

I used above formula to get sum, but it is not working..

Answer (score 1):

Put the formula below in cell B3 and drag it all the way on the right :

```
=SUMIF(Sheet1!$C$2:$C$17,Sheet2!B2,Sheet1!$D$2:$D$17)
```

In cell A3, you can put `=SUM(B3:E3)`. And finally, that's how looks like `Sheet2`:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Look into using SUMIF statements. Its always worth checking that all of your data has the same format and spelling as this can cause the statement not to work correctly.